How to read background syscall executed by pod on Linux VM
I have a K8S Pod which is running on a Linux Vm. It has some security policies applied ( blocks some syscalls, & allows some).  When my application executes this python code resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE), I see a PermissionError error
I just want to understand which syscall is getting executed in the background so that I can allow it. I tried to tail the audit logs at sudo tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log when the event happens but they don't look very useful. Which file will give me the syscalls in a human readable format?
This is the output of the /var/log/audit/audit.log when the application starts execution
type=UNKNOWN[1334] msg=audit(1723127982.604:3803): prog-id=484 op=LOAD
type=UNKNOWN[1334] msg=audit(1723127982.608:3804): prog-id=485 op=LOAD 
type=UNKNOWN[1334] msg=audit(1723127982.608:3805): prog-id=486 op=LOAD
...
type=UNKNOWN[1334] msg=audit(1723127982.648:3812): prog-id=493 op=LOAD 
type=UNKNOWN[1334] msg=audit(1723127991.012:3813): prog-id=486 op=UNLOAD 
type=UNKNOWN[1334] msg=audit(1723127991.180:3814): prog-id=491 op=UNLOAD 
...
type=UNKNOWN[1334] msg=audit(1723127991.532:3821): prog-id=484 op=UNLOAD 
type=UNKNOWN[1334] msg=audit(1723127991.532:3822): prog-id=488 op=UNLOAD

The pod and the process gets killed instantly, so exec inside it is not an option.

The getrlimit() and setrlimit() system calls get and set resource limits.Looking through GNU's libc manual, it has this to say on the current (soft) and hard limits:
Also refer to this github issue for more details where it tells that you should print the rlimit before this line, and make sure rlimit1> 20480 (if not, change 20480 to 2048 or other number).

Also please be noted that the number of open files is limited by the operating system.On linux you can type
ulimit -n (to see what the limit is)
If you are root, you can type
ulimit -n 2048
Now your program will run ok (as root) since you have lifted the limit to 2048 open files.And to  change the limit of open file handles on Linux, you can use the Python module resource. And to know more about the syscall refer to this.

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.What should I do when someone answers my question?
